# Sveltekit, console throws Error 500 when backend is down or during end of build-time

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, sveltekit-adapter-node

How to setup a maintenance page with error code 503? The app shows error 500 if the backend is down for maintenance or when the "Using @sveltejs/adapter-node" during build-time (i.e: npm run build/ vite build), is there a specific way to display maintenance page during build-time along with error 503

More information:

- Using Adapter node
- Using NGINX
- Backend NodeJS, CMS : Strapi
- Tools used - PM2

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect someone to help you if you don't post any code and in particular the code that is causing the 500

Comment: Well it ain't the code that's causing the error 500 (I should've made it clear earlier, my bad), in other words I wish to setup a maintenance page with error code - 503. 

Whenever I re-build the project using npm run build (or vite build) the page app goes offline once - "Using @sveltejs/adapter-node" shows up. I wish to show the maintenance page and 503 till the time the build is complete and the app is restarted.

I've tried using .env variables in layout.server.js and that works but in runtime, I wish to use the same for the whole app but during build time.

Answer (score 1):

If your SvelteKit "backend" is down, I assume that means your entire SvelteKit app is down.

You should replace the standard Nginx error page with your own - specifically targeting error 503.

```html
<!-- /usr/share/nginx/html/503.html -->
<h1>Oops! Something went wrong...</h1>
<p>We seem to be having some technical difficulties. Hang tight.</p>
```

More information:

- [Nginx "Http_Core_Module / Error_Page"](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)
- [DigitalOcean "How To Configure Nginx to Use Custom Error Pages on Ubuntu 22.04"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Thankyou, I will take a look at it